# Visual Studio 2017 With SpecFlow

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, specflow

I am running VS 2015 and VS 2017 side-by-side. I have installed TechTalk's SpecFlow from Nuget plus Nunit, the same on both VS versions. When I try to Add New Item a new feature file I can do this on VS 2015 but on VS 2017 I can't see the SpecFlow feature template, or, indeed, any SpecFlow template. The reference to specflow is definitely in the references; there's a configsetting in the app.config for Specflow.

How do I start with SpecFlow in VS 2017 [v15.2 (26430.16) Release; .NET 4.6.01055; SpecFlow v2.2.0] ?  Is SpecFlow even usable on VS 2017?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use specflow in VS:

- you need to install specflow extension (for your VS version)
- then install specflow nuget package
  it's better to restart VS in between.
- for version < 3, then make sure you have "**Enable SpecflowSingleFile Generator**" set to **false** in (**tools>options>specflow**)
- for version 3 onward, set to **true**

Answer (score 8):

For item templates, intellisense and some other features you need to install the SpecFlow Visual Studio Extension in Visual Studio.

Extension for VS 2015: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TechTalkSpecFlowTeam.SpecFlowforVisualStudio2015

Extension for VS 2017: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TechTalkSpecFlowTeam.SpecFlowforVisualStudio2017

After installation you have the item templates available.

Comment: Getting Errors: 
#error Version conflict - SpecFlow Visual Studio extension attempted to use SpecFlow code-behind generator 1.9, but project 'TestProject' references SpecFlow 3.0.
#error We recommend migrating to MSBuild code-behind generation to resolve this issue.
#error For more information see https://specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild/

Answer (score 2):

Andreas' answer is correct - the answer is to install the extension. However, the Download button on the URL above seems to do nothing, so it's best to install the extension from Visual Studio (select “Tools”, “Extensions and Updates…” from the menu. Click on "Online" on the left, and search for "SpecFlow")  Make sure **all** your open instances of VS are closed down to complete the installation, then 'Modify'.

Comment: Getting errors:
#error Version conflict - SpecFlow Visual Studio extension attempted to use SpecFlow code-behind generator 1.9, but project 'TestProject' references SpecFlow 3.0.
#error We recommend migrating to MSBuild code-behind generation to resolve this issue.
#error For more information see https://specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild/